# RabbitMQ only listens to the first message on a queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm having an issue with my Rabbit queues that is currently only reacting to the first message in queue, after that any other messages being pushed are being ignored.

I start with instantiating the connection and declaring the queue in my IQueueConnectionProvider:

```
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName };
var connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
var channel = connection.CreateModel();
```

That IQueueConnectionProvider is then used in my IQueueListener as a dependency with just one method:

```
public void ListenToQueue(string queue)
{
    var channel = _queueConnectionProvider.GetQueue();

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        string path = @"d:\debug.log.txt";
        File.AppendAllLines(path, new List<string>() {"MESSAGE RECEIVED", Environment.NewLine });

        var body = ea.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queue, true, consumer);

}
```

My log file ends up being just one line "MESSAGE RECEIVED", however I can see in the Rabbit ui interface that my other services are pushing the messages to that queue just fine.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a dumb mistake... yet again.

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue, false, consumer);
```

This was what I needed. I want to manually acknowledge my messages, therefore `noAck` needs to be `false`;

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine! Have tested with my queue, and was able to get "MESSAGE RECEIVED" 9 times in the log file; since I had 9 messages in my queue.

I tried without this line of code, and it worked fine
var channel = _queueConnectionProvider.GetQueue();